# wpdb object is calling ajax but not inserting data into the database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am using the WordPrewss `$wpdb` class to insert data into the database. The ajax part works fine but it's not addin the data into the database.

```js
    <script>
                $("#notes_maker").submit(function(){
                event.preventDefault();
                var formURL = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php')?>";
                var notes_editor = $("#notes_area").val();
                //var note_timestamp = $(".note_timestamp").text();

                $.ajax({
                    url: formURL,
                    data: {
                        'type': 'POST',
                        'action': 'notes',
                        'notes_editor1': notes_editor,
                        'dataType': 'text',
                        //'note_timestamp': note_timestamp,
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert("it works");
                    }
                })

                });
            </script>
```

```html
<form id="notes_maker" class="notes_section">
    <div class="note_timestamp">1.40</div>
    <div data-section="notes" class="js-tabs o-wrapper" id="notes">
      <textarea name="notes_area1" id="notes_area">
         this is some text
      </textarea>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Note"/>
     <input type="button" name="cancel_note" value="Cancel"/>
                </div>
            </form>
```

**functions.php file**

```
function my_ajax_notes() {
if(isset($_REQUEST)) {
  $car = $_REQUEST['notes_editor1'];

  echo $car;

global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert(
  $wpdb->prefix.`activity_notes`,
   [
    'text' => $car
    ]
  );
}

}

add_action('wp_ajax_notes', 'my_ajax_notes');
//add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_notes', 'my_ajax_notes');
```

Comment: Could you explain what what it is you want.  Showing WP code does not help .   So if the ajax works then the PHP script that gets called is the problem.   I see nothing in your code regarding "inserting data into a database".  Got an sql query?  Where are the parameters required to do the sql are being passed to the ajax function?

Comment: @Misunderstood in wordpress, it uses the $wpdb object and used the insert statement as you can see above in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding of your question I have reproduced your issue and made some changes to the code. Here it is:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="notes_maker" class="notes_section" type="POST">
<div class="note_timestamp">1.40</div>
<div data-section="notes" class="js-tabs o-wrapper" id="notes">
    <textarea name="notes_area1" id="notes_area">this is some text</textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Note" id="submit" />
    <input type="button" name="cancel_note" value="Cancel" />
</div>
```

**script:**

```
 (function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#notes_maker").submit(function(){
            event.preventDefault();
            var formURL = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php')?>";
            var notes_editor = $("#notes_area").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: formURL,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'text',
                data: {
                    'action': 'notes',
                    'notes_editor1': notes_editor,
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("it works");
                }
            })
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Then I added the blog_activity_notes table to my database. Here **blog** is my prefix.
[image]

**functions.php**

```
 function my_ajax_notes() {
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST ) ) {
        $car = $_REQUEST['notes_editor1'];

        echo $car;

        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->insert(
            $wpdb->prefix . 'activity_notes',
            array(
                'text' => $car,
            )
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_notes', 'my_ajax_notes' );
```

Please check once your table name whether the prefix is added or not. If not then you have to add a prefix to your table name.
It is working fine in my local and data has been inserted.

Comment: so this worked but it means I have to replace ` $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . 'activity_notes',` with ` $wpdb->insert('wp_activity_notes',,`. Why is this?

Comment: In the wp-config.php file, you can define a database table prefix. By default, the prefix is "wp_", but you'll need to check on the actual value and use it to define your database table name. This value is found in the $wpdb->prefix variable. I think your database table prefix is different so you have to put just the table name(wp_activity_notes).

Comment: yes taking out the $preix and just adding it as 'wp_table_name' worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change ajax function

```
$.ajax({
        url: formURL,
        'type': 'POST', // put this out here
        'dataType': 'text', // put this out here
         data: {
           'action': 'notes',
           'notes_editor1': notes_editor,
         },
         success: function(data) {
             alert("it works");
         }
});
```

and also make sure if the endpoint allows the **dataType**  you are sending

and may want to read about network inspection where you can see what is going on with your requests

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/#load

---